Définiton de "sarcassier" ?
Je suis tombé sur le mot "sarcassier" dans le roman Le pont de Londres de Céline :

"Tranquille ! on se retrouvera ce soir ! Y avait de la promesse.
Sarcassiers de mes couilles ! Du sport me voici !"

Après une recherche Google, j'ai également trouvé ce mot dans le livre L’homme hors de lui de Valère Novarina, où il est utilisé dans des expressions comme :

"L’Un des Mangeurs Sarcassiers"
"L’Enfant Sarcassier"

Je ne trouve pas de définition pour ce terme dans les dictionnaires que j'ai consultés. Quelqu'un pourrait-il m'expliquer le sens de ce mot ?

C'est une invention de l'auteur. Ce sont peut-être de « sarcastiques carnassiers » comme le suggère Thierry Thoulze dans sa thèse de doctorat Le sacrifice comique de Valère Novarina (2010).
